# Cannot change the font using font-family in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-family

I am new to wordpress and web development. I would like to modify a theme in wordpress but I have a problem. I tried to override the font-family using style.css in the editor, but it doesn't seem to help.
I wrote the following:

```
html, body {
    font-family: Gafata;
}
```

It doesn't override the original code. What could be my next steps in resolving the problem?Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding !important?

Comment: @Howlin yes, doesn't help :(

Comment: Try after clearing the cache in browser

Comment: have you added google fonts link in header or included @font-face

Comment: Try to inspect some element with crome deweloper tools. To see wher is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top of your CSS.

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gafata");
```

If you are not getting the font at that point update your

```
html, body {
font-family: Gafata;
}
```

to

```
html, body {
font-family: Gafata!important;
}
```

You could use class names on your html, and body tags. If you do not want to use !important.

Like

```
html.someClass, body.someOtherClass {
font-family: Gafata;
}
```

Other useful info https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started